# Alternative of many parameters in method?

Tags: php, software-design

I think I am passing too many parameters in the method

When user submit a form, for example:

```
public function addServer(CreateRequest $request)
{
    $created = $this->server->create(
                  $request->name,
                  $request->location, 
                  $request->plan,
                  $request->php_version,
                  $request->install_mysql,
                  $request->database_name,
                  $request->do_backup,
                );
}
```

Sometime I wouldn't need all that parameters above, just a few.

In server class:

```
class Server {
   public function create($name, $location, $plan, $phpVersion, $installMysql, $databaseName, $doBackup) {
        $server =  $this->create($name, $location, $plan);

        if ($server) { 
        }   
   } 
}
```

Would passing an object (entity) solve this?

Comment: https://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern):

> the intention of the builder pattern is to find a solution to the telescoping constructor anti-pattern[citation needed]. The telescoping constructor anti-pattern occurs when the increase of object constructor parameter combination leads to an exponential list of constructors. Instead of using numerous constructors, the builder pattern uses another object, a builder, that receives each initialization parameter step by step and then returns the resulting constructed object at once.

Basically with a builder pattern you guarantee that your object is initialised properly at all times, with or without optional properties.

You would create an additional `ServerBuilder` class which would have a setter for each property/parameter for a Server, and a `build()` method which returns a `Server` instance.

```
class ServerBuilder {
    private $name = "";
    private $location = null;

    public function name($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function location($location) {
        $this->location = $location;
        return $this;
    }

    /* add other setters here .. */

    public function build() {
        // here you ensure all properties have sane values
        // if no php_version then set default etc
        return new Server($name, $location, ..., ..., etc);
    }
}
```

You would use it like:

```
$builder = new ServerBuilder();
$server = $builder
    ->name("foo")
    ->location("bar")
    ->build();
```

Comment: builder pattern is interesting. Each server provider have different properties requirement. I could use switch statement (provider name) in the `build()` method.

Answer (score 0):

1. You may pass the `$request` variable to `Server->create`, or `Sever->createFromObject`, whatever you want. `CreateRequest`, or an other object can hold any data you need, and later you check which is eg. `null`, which paramteres weren't passed.
2. Create more methods, for each separatable parts. Eg. `createServer($name, $location, $plan), setBackup(bool), setMysql($dbName)`, and so on. And you call only those you need when you create a server.